# (GitHub Actions) Split step into two consecutive ones

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I'd like to use GitHub Actions to publish an npm package. So far I am using quite a trivial script to do that. Now I'd like to split one step of the script into two consecutive ones.
here's an excerpt from my workflows/...yaml file:

```yaml
    steps:
    # ...
    - name: Build
      run: |
        cd src
        npm install
        tsc

        # TODO split here

        npm set registry https://npm.pkg.github.com
        npm set //npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        npm publish
      env:
        CI: true
```

Now, when I tried to have these as separate Steps, they ran in parallel which is not the behavior I hope for, since the first step yields results (creates a src/lib directory) that I depend on in step #2. (The one where I log into npm and publish this).

Can someone please help me to unravel this?

Comment: steps do not execute in parallel. Can you show what you did to make them run in parallel

Comment: @smac89 I am quite happy that you asked me to share my setup. I recreated the former setup by splitting the steps and it worked as intended.
I am not sure, how I got the impression, that it did not work in first place. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

As [@smac89](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2089675/smac89) explains above, `steps` can't be executed in parallel, only `jobs` and `workflows` can.

The [official Github Documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions) shares this illustration about the Github Actions structure:

[image: repository workflows]

What probably happened in your case was that you created 2 jobs instead of 2 steps.

The syntax to split your steps should be something like this:

```yaml
jobs:
  my-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest #for example
    steps:
    # ...
    - name: Build
      run: |
        cd src
        npm install
        tsc
      env:
        CI: true
   - name: Publish
     run: |
        npm set registry https://npm.pkg.github.com
        npm set //npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        npm publish
      env:
        CI: true
```